# Pass array data to component and make

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, mapbox-gl-js

I try to get familiar with Vue2.
As you can see below I try to pass in the "markers"-Array but the map does not change. How can I change the markers array? How can I make the markers array reactive so that map markers change?

Thanks for helping me!

```
views/Map.vue
```

```js
<template>
  <div id="MapWrapper">
    <Map :markers = "markers"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Map from 'src/components/MapSoal.vue'

export default {
  name: 'MapView',
  components: {
    Map
  },
  data () {
    return {
      markers: [
        {name: "greenMarker", lngLat: [13.8022177, 51.0069449], color: "green", text: "<h1>This is the green marker</h1>"},
        {name: "orangeMarker", lngLat: [13.8022177 - 0.05, 51.0069449], color: "orange", text: "<h1>this is the orange marker</h1>"},
      ]   
    }  
  }
}
</script>
```

```
components/MapSoal.vue
```

```js
<template>
  <MglMap 
    :accessToken="accessToken" 
    :mapStyle="mapStyle" 
    :center="center"
    :zoom="zoom"
  >
    <MglMarker v-for="marker in markers" :key="marker.name" :coordinates="marker.lngLat" :color="marker.color">
       <MglPopup>   
          <VCard v-html="marker.text"></VCard>
        </MglPopup>
    </MglMarker>
   <MglGeolocateControl></MglGeolocateControl>
   <MglNavigationControl></MglnavigationControl>
  </MglMap>
</template>

export default {
    data() {
        return {
          accessToken: 'SOME_API_KEY',
          mapStyle: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11?optimize=true',
          center: [13.8022177, 51.0069449],
          zoom: 9, // starting zoom
          markers: []
        };
      },    
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not declaring `markers` as a prop in your `Map` component, you're declaring markers in your data object, so the `Map` component's got a separate data variable named `markers`, completely unrelated to your parent component's data. Try removing your `markers` array from data in your `Map` component and add it in a `props` object in the component like this:

```
props: {
    markers: {
        type: Array
    }
},
```

or

```
props: ['markers'],
```

so that your `Map` component looks like this:

```
<template>
  <MglMap 
    :accessToken="accessToken" 
    :mapStyle="mapStyle" 
    :center="center"
    :zoom="zoom"
  >
    <MglMarker v-for="marker in markers" :key="marker.name" :coordinates="marker.lngLat" :color="marker.color">
       <MglPopup>   
          <VCard v-html="marker.text"></VCard>
        </MglPopup>
    </MglMarker>
   <MglGeolocateControl></MglGeolocateControl>
   <MglNavigationControl></MglnavigationControl>
  </MglMap>
</template>

export default {
    props: ['markers'],

    data() {
        return {
          accessToken: 'SOME_API_KEY',
          mapStyle: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11?optimize=true',
          center: [13.8022177, 51.0069449],
          zoom: 9, // starting zoom
        };
      },    
        
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! I already solved myself now. But it is hard to distinguish the certain concepts in Vue for a beginner!

Comment: Hey, no problem guy. Glad you managed to find it for yourself 